# Qual a melhor maneira de verificar se se uma coleção existe no cloudFirestore (Android)?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firestore

Estou tendo dificuldades em verificar a existência de uma coleção. Eu estou usando o seguinte código para executar esta função:

`FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("ID da COLEÇÃO").document("ID do DOCUMENTO").collection("ID da SUB-COLEÇÃO").get().addOnSucessLi.... & addOnFailureLi.....`

A minha intenção é saber se a coleção "ID da SUB-COLEÇÃO" existe para entrar no addOnSusse... e se não existe então entra no addOnFailu...

Entretanto, mesmo não existindo a "ID da SUB-COLEÇÃO", o addOnSuces... está sendo chamado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, André!

`onFailure` só é chamado se a requisição ao Firestore falhar. Para saber se algo existe, você precisa esperar o retorno de chamada ser bem sucedido em `onSuccess`.

Para resolver seu problema, espere `onSuccess` ser chamado e execute seu código:

```
firestore.collection("colecao_1")
        .document("documento_id")
        .collection("colecao_2")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(snapshots -> {
            if (snapshots.isEmpty()) {
               // Execute seu código aqui
            }
        })
```

Com essa verificação, temos duas certezas: que a `colecao_2` está vazia (o mais óbvio) ou que ela simplesmente não existe, o que para efeitos práticos, são a mesma coisa.

Espero que isso ajude!